# Makefile- How to define variables in a target that creates other targets?

Tags: makefile

I don't fully understand how to use target-specific variables to act as targets themselves, having their own dependencies and recipes.

Example Makefile that works but does not use target-specific variables:

```
VAR=progName
ATARGET: $(VAR)
    @echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $(VAR)
$(VAR):
    @echo Do actions on $@
```

> make ATARGET
>
> Do actions on progName
>
> Do actions for ATARGET based on the completed target progName

Makefile which does NOT work trying to use target-specific variables (note the lack of "Do actions on progName" when executing make):

```
ATARGET:VAR=progName
ATARGET: $(VAR)
    @echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $(VAR)
$(VAR):
    @echo Do actions on $@
```

> make ATARGET
>
> Do actions for ATARGET based on the completed target progName

Desired Makefile behavior:

```
ATARGET:VAR=progName
ATARGET: $(VAR)
    @echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $(VAR)

BTARGET:VAR=otherProgName
BTARGET: $(VAR)
    @echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $(VAR)

$(VAR):
    @echo Do actions on $@
```

> make ATARGET
>
> Do actions on progName
>
> Do actions for ATARGET based on the completed target progName
>
> make BTARGET
>
> Do actions on otherProgName
>
> Do actions for BTARGET based on the completed target otherProgName

These are simple Makefiles to illustrate the problem- the actual makefile has several targets depending on the value of VAR.

```
PGM = $(VAR)_test.exe;
LIB = lib$(VAR).a;
LIBLINKNAME = $(VAR);
```

Comment: The reason you don't fully understand it, is that what you're trying to do is not possible.  See the manual for target-specific variables, where it specifically states _As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe_.  Another rule definition is NOT "within the context of a target's recipe".  However, based on your other examples you don't need to do this anyway, as Wintermute shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the value of make variables depending on the target you're building; they are processed before all that. You can, however, have rules with multiple targets and produce your desired behavior with them. For example:

```
VAR = progName otherProgName

ATARGET: progName
    echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $<

BTARGET: otherProgName
    echo Do actions for $@ based on the completed target $<

$(VAR):
    echo Do actions on $@
```

`VAR` is now no longer a terribly good name (perhaps better to call it `LIST` or something). This way, the same recipe applies for the `progName` and `otherProgName` targets, and which one is generated depends on the prerequisites of the target you're building.

In conjunction with string-handling functions, this is adaptable for more complex use cases. For example, you could use

```
# pattern substitution: append _test.exe to all entries in VAR
PGM = $(VAR:%=%_test.exe)

$(PGM):
    recipe for individual *_test.exe programs here.
```

You may also be *very* interested in [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html).

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the answer is  "you can't do that, but you can achieve almost the same result another way". Will try that.